# Addition not working correctly in ExpressJs, Where subtraction is working correctly

Tags: node.js, express

I am doing a NodeJs Project. I am facing this problem.Subtraction is working correctly But addition is creating the problem.................

```
var previous_stock=results[0]['remain_stock']; //suppose value is 123
    var products_qty=request.body.products_qty;  //suppose valut is 7

    var update_data={
        remain_stock:previous_stock-products_qty, //output is 116
    }
    var update_data2={
        remain_stock:previous_stock+products_qty, //output is 1237
    }
```

How to solve that problem??

Comment: Use parseInt on both variables to explicitly type conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When used on a `String`, the `+` operator concatenates, even if the `String` only consists of digits. Assuming all your string values are base 10, wrap them in `parseInt(string, 10)`. Note that you should also do this to `products_qty` if it's a `String`.

```
var previous_stock = results[0].remain_stock
var products_qty = request.body.products_qty

var update_data = {
  remain_stock: parseInt(previous_stock, 10) - products_qty
}

var update_data2 = {
  remain_stock: parseInt(previous_stock, 10) + products_qty
}
```

Comment: Because the subtraction operator isn't defined, so your `String` is coerced to a `Number`. This is bad for performance and stability, you should avoid coercion by using the actual types you intend.